# Application crash after updating Device to android Kitkat 4.4.3

Tags: android, crash, android-4.4-kitkat, android-anr-dialog

Few days back I launch an application to google play store.It was running amazingly in most of the device from android 2.2 to 4.4.2.But for some other devices which have received updates for 4.4.3 ,the application is not even running and for some devices like nexus 4 it says that your application is not compatible with this Os Version.

> Even my app won't show for other devices as well which have android
>   version between 2.2 to 4.4.

Am I going wrong somewhere ??

Or is it a bug with android kitkat 4.4.3 ??

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" 
    >

    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" /> 
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!--all large size screens  -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
   </compatible-screens>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application 

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" 
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
     </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You must post your manifest file. Plus, this is not even a crash.

Comment: posted manifest file @jyoon

Comment: Remove the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: @jyoon: Can you explain why we have to remove READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: @Pankaj: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: No,still I didn't get exact solution for this @roymathew

Comment: @Pankaj: Same issue is happening to my application also. I think it has something to do with the image loading in 4.4.3. I can't find any emulator with 4.4.3 to test the issue.